# SQL: get monthly sales together with sales of the last four months

Tags: sql, postgresql

What I need is to aggregate the sales by center and month and also get the sales of the last 4 months.

This is the table that I have:

```
center_id   month_id    sales_amt
1           201512      1000
1           201511      2000
1           201510      1500
1           201509      1700
1           201508      900
...
```

This is what I need:

```
center_id   month_id    sales_amt   sales_4_month
1           201512      1000        6200
1           201511      2000        6100
...
```

Comment: Did you try something? Show your work! From the [stackoverflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour): "Don't ask about: Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions to achieve this:

```
select 
center_id, month_id, sales_amt,
(
sales_amt + 
lead (sales_amt,1,0) over (PARTITION BY center_id ORDER BY month_id desc) +
  lead (sales_amt,2,0) over (PARTITION BY center_id ORDER BY month_id desc) +
  lead (sales_amt,3,0) over (PARTITION BY center_id ORDER BY month_id desc)
) sales_4_month
from Sales
```

It should be faster than subquery, but you must not forget to select 3 more months than you need! Otherwise, the lead function will not have a row to calculate from.

Comment: yep, it should be much faster

Answer (score 0):

Easy way. Just add subquery to SELECT

```
SELECT 
  center_id, month_id, sales_amt, (
    SELECT SUM(sub.sales_amt) 
    FROM foo sub 
    WHERE sub.month_id >= base.month_id-4
  ) as sales_4_month
FROM foo base
```

U also can use CTE

Comment: this will have trouble when the interval is between years